# How to start a VM in a Singularity container?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, singularity-container

So I want to spit up a `Windows.iso` I have on a **cluster** node using ***Singularity*** images. I tried VirtualBox yet got this exception:

```
ingularity virtualbox:~> virtualbox  WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module  available for the current kernel (4.17.3-200.fc28.x86_64) or it failed to  load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by 

sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup 

You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Note that singularity image can not have sudo so all preparations are done in Docker image from which I create a singularity image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need install the virtualbox's kernel module outside the container, on your host system, then load it before run container. depending the Distro that you have, it may be necessary to build it from source source.